# jquery how can i animate a child div to the right out of the parent div?

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I want to animate the width of the child div to break out of the parent div.
In my code which I am linking the child, div animates inside of the parent div but not outside of it.

Please help. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n6Lg4q5h/14/)

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  drop = false;
  $(".parent").click(() => {
    if (drop == true) {
      $(".child").animate({
        width: "0px"
      });
      drop = false;
    } else if (drop == false) {
      $(".child").animate({
        width: "200px"
      });
      drop = true;
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.child {
  width: 0px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [ask] and [edit] your question to include your code. You can create a runnable Stack Snippet using the `[<>]` button on the editor toolbar. External links are ok, but only when the relevant code is also included here, as external links can break or change over time and the question is no longer useful to other users. Also, what you are asking is a little unclear - what do you mean by "animate outside of the parent"? If you don't want to to overlap the parent, could you change it from being a child to a sibling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say you want the child to animate outside the parent to the right, I assume you mean for it to slide out of the parent element.

You are already setting the width in your jQuery, so you just need to set the `right` to a negative number to make it extend the opposite direction, e.g.:

```
  $(".child").animate({width: "200px", right: "-200px" });
```

Then to reset it, just set `right:0`, e.g.

```
  $(".child").animate({width: "0px", right:"0"});
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(()=> {

    drop = false;
  
  $(".parent").click(()=> {
    if(drop == true) {   
      $(".child").animate({width: "0px", right:"0"});
      drop = false;
      
    } else if(drop == false) {  
      $(".child").animate({width: "200px", right: "-200px" });
      drop = true;     
    }
  })

});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.child {
  width: 0px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
   <div class="parent">     
      <div class="child">        
      </div>     
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the width to for example 400px and it will expand to 400px. You can use 100% to match the red box or use 150% to be with 50% more than the red box.

If you want to grow to the right, change the css of the `.child` `right: 0` to `left: 0`.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  drop = false;
  $(".parent").click(() => {
    if (drop == true) {
      $(".child").animate({
        width: "0px"
      });
      drop = false;
    } else if (drop == false) {
      $(".child").animate({
        width: "400px"
      });
      drop = true;
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.child {
  width: 0px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the child div to expand to the right not to the left.

Comment: As mentioned change `right` to `left`. The answer is updated. Is that what you need?

Comment: not exactly, now the child is animating from the left to the right inside the parent div. I want it to still be right and expand to the right.